# How to Update and Delete record in JavaEE using JSTL, JPA, EJB, JSP, Servlet

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, servlets, jpa, ejb

I have managed to persist data into db but I am not able to update the data and delete. I think I am going wrong way or something needs to be fixed. I am learning JavaEE myself following JavaEE Ecommerce tutorial from Netbeans. I have gone through all lessons and now adding features to this app to make it real world app as this example lesson is lacking many things but until now I am just able to make the data persist to db. 
Here I want to know how can i fix it and What is the better way to do this to make it work.

Here is Read part with buttons to delete and update. It is able to show list of data from MySQL.

```
<c:if test="${!empty categoryList}">

                    <h2>Category List</h2>
                    <table class="table">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Category Id:</th>
                            <th>Category Name:</th>
                            <th>Edit</th>
                            <th>Delete</th>
                        </tr>
                        <c:forEach var="category" items="${categoryList}" varStatus="iter">
                            <tr>
                            <td>${category.id}</td>
                            <td>${category.name}</td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-danger" alt="Update" href='updateCategory.jsp?id=<c:out value="${category.id}"/>'><i class="fa fa-cut"></i></a></td>
                            <td><a class="btn btn-danger" alt="Delete" href='deleteCategory.jsp?action=delete&id=<c:out value="${category.id}"/>'><i class="fa fa-cut"></i></a></td>
                            </tr>
                        </c:forEach>
                    </table>
            </c:if>
```

**updateCategory.jsp**

```
<h1>Edit Category: </h1>
                <form id ="addCatForm" action="<c:url value='/admin/updateCategory?id=${param.id} '/>" method="post">
                    <c:if test="${!empty validationErrorFlag}">
                        <c:if test="${!empty nameError}"><p>Fill Category Name</p></c:if>
                    </c:if>

            <input type="hidden" name="id" value="${param.id}" />

                    <p><strong>Category Name:</strong>
                    <input class ="form-control" type="text" value ="${param.name}" name="name"></p>
                    <p><input class ="btn-success" type="submit" value="Submit"></p>

                </form>
```

**Part from AdminServlet handling Update:**

```
else if (userPath.equals("/admin/updateCategory")){
             //Integer category_id = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("category_id")) ;
            String category_id = request.getParameter("category_id");
             category = categoryFacade.find(Integer.parseInt(category_id));
             String name = request.getParameter("name");
             boolean validationErrorFlag;
                validationErrorFlag = validator.validateForm(name, request);
                // if validation error found, return  to same
                if (validationErrorFlag == true) {
                    request.setAttribute("validationErrorFlag", validationErrorFlag);

                }
                else {
                    try{
                        request.setAttribute("name" , name);
                    //userPath = "/admin/showCategory";
                    //categoryManager.updateCategory(name, category_id);
                        categoryManager.updateCategory(name);
                    }
                    catch(Exception ex){
                        ex.toString();
                    }
                }                                                                        }
```

**update and delete part from CategoryManager.java**

```
public Category updateCategory(String name) {
        //public Category updateCategory(String name, int category_id) {
            Category category = new Category();

            category.setName(name);
            //category.setId(category_id);
            em.merge(category); 
            return category;


        }
        public Category deleteCategory(int id){
            Category category = new Category();
            category.setId(id);
            em.remove(category); 
            return category;
        }
```

Comment: You have mentioned id as a parameter `updateCategory.jsp?id=` but in method using `category_id` as a parameter

Comment: like this `request.getParameter("category_id");` in **AdminServlet**

Comment: ya i was mistaken on id part.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the code were correct but It was small thing that was missing in my AdminServlet as I had guessed before. 
actually url pattern was missing

```
urlPatterns = {
                            "/admin/",
                            "/admin/viewOrders",
                            "/admin/viewCustomers",
                            "/admin/customerRecord",
                            //"/admin/customerOrder",
                            "/admin/orderRecord",
                            "/admin/logout",
                            "/admin/showProduct",
                            "/admin/showCategory",
                            "/admin/addCategory",
                            "/admin/addCategory.jsp",
                            "/admin/updateCategory",
                            "/admin/addProduct",
                            "/admin/addProduct.jsp",
                            "/admin/deleteProduct.jsp",
                            "/admin/deleteProduct"

                            })
```

Otherway of categoryManager though above also works.

```
public Category updateCategory(Category category, String name){

        category.setName(name);
        em.merge(category); 

        return category;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no code for invoking the deletion, so make sure the deleteCategory of CategoryManager is actually called.

But apart from it the code should be:

```
public Category deleteCategory(int id){
    Category category = em.find(Category.clas,id);
    em.remove(category); 
    return category;
}
```

and for update you need to know the id of the category to update

```
public Category updateCategory(int id, String name) {
    Category category = em.find(Category.class,id);
    category.setName(name);
    return category;
}
```

Both methods must be called in transaction context, but if you are using Java EE it is taken care of (if not you need to call `em.getTransaction().begin()`... `em.getTransaction().commit()`)

Comment: I think for update part we need em.merge(category). Did you forget or its not necessary?

Comment: I did not, it is not necessery in the current code. The category is obtained by em.find so it is already known to the em. You would use merge if you passed the modified category as the input parameter to the method instead of its id.

Comment: one thing i noticed. I already have  category = categoryFacade.find(Integer.parseInt(category_id)); in my servlet then Why do we need  Category category = em.find(Category.class,id); in CategoryManager. I think its redundant. Am i wrong? @Ziela

Comment: I was not checking your servlet code just the manager. If you have it than you use it as it is as long as your servlet and manager are using same entity manager

Comment: ok. But i tried your code but its not working. its not updating even using your way. I think problems are in other part please check where i have mistaken. I am currently just testing update part.

Comment: add println to the manager methods to check if they are invoked at all (and with the correct id). Probbly not, as they should work. If they are, then make sure you have a transaction started and commited (I dont see any places in your code that does that).

Comment: i have used container managed transaction using @TransactionManagement(TransactionManagementType.CONTAINER)